# Using multiple .properties files for the same selenium test case using protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have written some test cases to test the UI functionality of a web app.

The thing is the app supports multiple modes using different .properties file.

The code inside the describe functions are the same for both modes and the only change is the .properties file.

How can i select a different .properties file based on the mode and run the same cases.

I am using Jasmine on protractor.

Like this?

[image]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: you should write a configurationReader method that takes the path of the properties file as a parameter, so you can call that method with the properties file that correspont to your needs. I would have gave you the code but I only know hoe to do it in java not javascript

Comment: @mbn217 I have updated the original post is this a way to do it?

Comment: @SharathPrakash Im really not sure how javascript works but i think the code is correct. You method parameter have to be your path. So everytime you need to a diffrent properties file you just call the method with the path to the corresponded properties file

Comment: Thanks will try it.